# How to use input from adress "Something.webpage.com" and use the input "something"

Tags: javascript, css, html

Im not sure what to search for on google to find help for this so I choose to write here.

so lets say you have a site called "isadouchebag.com"
then if you write "Brian.isadouchebag.com" it will say on the site "Brian is a douchebag" - how do I do this so I can take that input "Brian" and use it on my page to do something, without hardcoding every name.

Comment: Use your .htacess to do a server side rewrite of the URL. Essentailly you want isadouchebag.com?myvar=Brian to be rewritten as brian.isadouchebag.com.  http://serverfault.com/questions/203780/troubleshooting-a-htaccess-wildcard-subdomain-rewrite/203804#203804

Comment: You'd have to do some backend stuff or setup every subdomain, but it's not possible with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript window.location.hostname is gonna give you the full domain name: "Brian.isadouchebag.com" you then take that string and just parse it until the first "." and you have your name.

You would also have to setup your hosting to accept wildcard subdomains(*) for every subdomain to work (Brian.isadouchebag.com, bob.isadouchebag.com...)

Comment: meh I suppose, I hope he realizes he'll have to buy that specific domain xD

Comment: It was an example ;) - not gonna make a domain called that guys